# No way my laptop will use nVidia chip instead of integrated graphics

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card, switchable-graphics

I have tried everything I could find out there, but there is just no way my laptop sets the nVidia GPU as primary chip. I have a 28" 4K monitor plugged on the DisplayPort, and it keeps using the Intel integrated graphics.

System : W7 x64 laptop, core i7, 16 GB RAM, nVidia 880M

I have set "**Force nVidia**" in the nVidia control panel, rebooted, no effect at all. Keeps using Intel.

I have uninstalled nVidia drivers, **reinstalled the latest one**, rebooted, no effect.

I have forced **disabling the Intel chip**, but the PC restarts as if there is no other graphics card installed, without Aero effects and with very laggy display.

I have enabled "**High performance mode**" in energy settings.

My **BIOS** is mainly informative and does not allow disabling, forcing or acting on the graphics cards.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Whatever I do, I still have laggy display on my huge 4K monitor because the laptop just won't use the nVidia chip.

I would greatly appreciate a miracle solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: What make and model is the laptop? Normally this is disabled in the BIOS which I understand you have attempted.

Comment: It's a generic laptop. I bought it without OS. Here's the link : http://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB00165710.html

Comment: Can you use the 880M for the internal display?

Comment: As far as I Know, if there is no option in BIOS, then the system switches graphics by itself depending on the graphics load (in the 3D games it should switch to nVidia). 
Can you just disable Intel Graphics in device manager?

Comment: @Hardoman the OP has already tried that *"I have forced disabling the Intel chip, but the PC restarts as if there is no other graphics card installed, without Aero effects and with very laggy display."*

Comment: @JeremyThille do you know what motherboard it uses? They might have a generic BIOS on their website. I dusted off my high school French and had a look at the LDLC website, it is pretty poor for tech support though.

Comment: According to CPU-z, the mainboard is a P15SM-A/SM1-A, the northbridge is Intel Haswell and the southbridge Intel HM87. The laptop manufacturer would in fact be Clevo. I'm gonna look for a bios update, but I don't like that, as it is quite a hazardous operation and I doubt a new bios will suddenly allow tuning the graphics card.

Comment: It looks like games are using the nVidia chip, because I can play in 4K with high settings and they're fluid. However, Windows itself keeps using the integrated graphics, and thus is quite laggy when it comes to scrolling, moving stuff around and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your laptop, all your displays are connected to the Integrated GPU (the Haswell - based Intel HD Graphics 4600), something you can confirm by:

1. Navigating to the "Set PhysX configuration" tab on the Nvidia Control Panel. It will show you how these displays are wired to the Intel Integrated Graphics controller.
2. Opening the Intel HD Graphics control panel, from where you'll be able to adjust advanced display settings for the 4k panel you have.

You mentioned that the 4k display panel is connected via DisplayPort, correct? In that case, you'll want to turn on DisplayPort MST (Multi-Stream Support) IF such an option is available. Its' often enabled for Daisy chained setups and where the same panel is fed by two DisplayPort 1.2a cables.

An example of such a setup where DisplayPort MST would be of use would be with a single Dell Ultra HD 4k Monitor P2715Q 27-Inch Screen LED-Lit Monitor , or a daisy-chained setup such as [this one here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN293813/how-to-configure-two-external-monitors-with-displayport-12-multi-stream-support-to-work-with-the-precision-m4800?lang=EN).

It would also be useful if you shared your monitor's make and model here, might help with troubleshooting.

**Notes from [Intel's Quick Reference Guide for the Intel 4th Generation Core Processor Graphics](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics), Haswell:**

The main requirement for supporting 4K@60 on DP SST (single-stream transport) is that the [core display clock](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_displayport.pdf) (CDCLK), which is configured by SBIOS, must be set high enough to drive the dot clock required by the mode.  Usually 4K@60 has a 536MHz dot clock, so it requires a 540MHz CDCLK. 
If the system OEM did not configure the CDCLK at 540MHz for thermal, power saving, or other reasons, then the system will not be able to drive 4K@60 over a single DP stream. Also, Haswell ULT (-U) and ULX (-Y) are limited to 450MHz and 337MHz CDCLK, so they will not be able to do 4K@60 SST.  ULT should still be able to do 4K@60 MST, though.  ULX can’t because 4K MST still requires HBR2.

This shouldn’t affect DP MST tiled displays because for those, Intel uses two streams, each for one half of the display, reducing the pixel clock.

Additionally, 4K support is only available on the Core processor graphics. Celeron and Pentium do not support 4K. All Core Haswell processors will support HBR2 with the exception of Haswell ULX.

[Here](http://download.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/Intel_Collage_Display_Feature_Rev1.pdf) is a reference guide that can be of help with Intel's Collage Mode, which controls DisplayPort's SST and MST modes.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. The "Set PhysX configuration" tab shows that both displays (laptop and 4k) are connected to the Intel HD. I can select "GeForce GTX 880M" in the dropdown, I clicked "Apply"... and it does nothing. I can't see "DisplayPort MST" option anywhere.

Comment: Hello, it would seem that my answer is correct, and that for some reason, DisplayPort MST is unavailable for your system. It's mostly activated with daisy chained setups  or a monitor with dual DisplayPort in ports. So for now you'll have to do with the Integrated Graphics solution. Secondly, the PhysX page does show the display output panel setup, however, it has no direct control on outputs UNLESS the Nvidia GPU is wired to a monitor directly, which is not the case here. Toggling the options here only enables Nvidia PhysX offload to the dedicated GPU.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this. It seems like there is no solution in my case, but all your assumptions and your answer being correct, I accepted it nonetheless. Cheers!