# MSI Laptop monitor uses integrated graphics vice NVIDIA card

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card

I have an MSI laptop with a 120hz-capable monitor and a NVIDIA GTX 1060. Unfortunately, the monitor is using the integrated graphics card for the display instead of the NVIDIA card. **How do I force it to use the NVIDIA card for the display instead of the integrated graphics card?**

**Issues I'm seeing:** This force-limits my refresh rate to 60hz and causes noticeable visual performance issues in everyday applications on Windows (e.g., the screen lags when dragging an Excel 2016 window across the screen)

**Observations:** I dual-booted into Ubuntu and the screen refresh rate is now 120hz. So, since it works on Ubuntu but not on Windows (by default), I know this should be solvable at the O/S-level.

**Similar questions that I've reviewed/attempted:**

1. [I have a NVIDIA GeForce graphics card as well as an integrated Intel HD graphics card](https://superuser.com/questions/1302304/i-have-a-nvidia-geforce-graphics-card-as-well-as-an-integrated-intel-hd-graphics)
2. [Integrated graphics card being used over NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M in Toshiba laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/801814/integrated-graphics-card-being-used-over-nvidia-geforce-gt-540m-in-toshiba-lapto)
3. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72567/can-i-force-steam-to-use-my-nvidia-gpu-instead-of-the-integrated-intel-card
4. [No way my laptop will use nVidia chip instead of integrated graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/1013611/no-way-my-laptop-will-use-nvidia-chip-instead-of-integrated-graphics)

Comment: Normally the integrated GPU is used for general desktop use, and the higher-end discrete GPU is only used on demand, when required. You should check drivers and firmware updates and look for documentation from MSI on this issue, to begin with.

Comment: I don't think there is any thing wrong with your GTX 1060.Windows is decided to just use integrated graphics if you just open daily applications, it is windows's Characteristics. But if you play a

Comment: You can set your computer in high performance in power management. What's more. in Navidia 3D settings, set in high performance.